# How to run magento files on local server?

Tags: magento

I have done one work which is stored in the webserver. I downloaded all the files and the database and uploaded onto the local server.When I am typing the local server url ,its going to the web server url.Also when i am logging onto the admin panel in magento in local server, its going to the admin panel in the webserver.How can it be corrected ? Actually I am new to Magento.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to update base url in your database. Open your phpmyadmin, go to `core_config_data` and update your new url. Use below mysql query,

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value="http://localhost/your-magento-location" WHERE path='web/unsecure/host';
```

Don't forget to clear cache.

> *Note: Please consider that, before ask question here, you should have search in google. If you are not able to find answer, then you can ask
>   here.*

Comment: in the cache tab, all the options are showing disabled. and also all the images are in broken state.

Comment: Just delete ROOT/var/cache directory. And execute the query. It will work.

Comment: still the images are in broken state.